# Can not update database when missing field in json

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5.1

I am making an api that can help user update their info follow the input data. But when in input json have field "password" it will update successfully but when json don't have this field i can not update data in database. This is code i used to update data:

```
public function updateUserInfo(Request $request){
        $postData = $request->all();
        $data = json_decode($postData['postData'], true);
        if(isset($data['password'])){
            $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        }
        $popData = $data['UserId'];
        unset($data['UserId']);
        $updateInfo = array();
        foreach($data as $info){
            if($info != null){
                $updateInfo[] = $info;
            }
        }
        $result =  DB::update(GeneralFunctions::makeUpdateString($data, 'User', ' UserId = '.$popData), $updateInfo);
        if($result != null && $result == true){
            return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'data'=>'Update Successful']);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'error'=>'We have encountered an error, try again later!']);
        }
    }
```

This is the json when everything work fine:

```
$postData = '{ "UserId" : "1",   "password":"12345", "UserName": "minhkhang",  "Address": "11/200" }'
```

This is the json which will cause error because it is missing password field:

```
$postData = '{ "UserId" : "1", "UserName": "minhkhang",  "Address": "11/200" }'
```

This is code i used to make update string follow input json:

```
 public static function makeUpdateString($keyvalarr, $table, $where){
        $stringSQL = 'UPDATE '.$table. ' SET ' ;
        foreach($keyvalarr as $fieldname => $updateval){
            if($updateval != null){
                $stringSQL .= $fieldname.' = ? , ';
            }
        }
        $stringSQL =  substr($stringSQL, 0, -2);
        if($where != null){
            $stringSQL .= 'WHERE '.$where;
        }
        return $stringSQL;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The code in question here is:

```
if(isset($data['password'])){
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
}
```

Check to see what

```
isset($data['password'])
```

is returning outside the if statement, if it is true for password being present in the JSON and not giving you an issue that sounds like what you'd expect, however check to see if that statement by itself is false without the if statement, make sure it isn't still jumping into that, it seems to be the only place your looking for `'password'`

Comment: so how can i fix this problem, i have tried to use isset to check if this key is available in array in other project but it is working fine. Do not know why this make a problem in this function!

Comment: What does it return if there is no 'password' in the JSON? by itself, also have you considered removing that entire section of code if you plan to not use the 'password'? or do you need to use it?, if you have tried that already, have you considered that when it passes in $data into the function, that if the JSON isn't matching when it tried to apply the keys to the fields, and run the UPDATE?  Could the keys be mismatching what the table is expecting? are you getting any specific errors that may help more?

Comment: If password is not available in json or null then  i need to unset that key. If it is availabel i must hash it with bcrypt and set again to the array

Comment: In that case, you might just need to add an else with the `unset` right after that if statement, such that `else { unset($data['password']); }`

Comment: Any chance you can post what you have tried in the original question?